# I am ahead by 1 commit in git but I have already pushed all my commits

Tags: git, gitlab, repository, commit

I am working with a remote repository on GitLab and when I check git status, it tells me I am ahead by 1 commit, even though I haven't changed anything (neither added nor committed) since my last push. So I did git log to check whether I committed something, and it shows the following two commits as the latest:

commit abc (HEAD -> main)
Author: someone_else
Date: Sat Nov 11

commit abc2 (origin/main, origin/HEAD)
Author: me
Date: Fri Nov 10

The commit abc2 is the only commit I have made so far, and I already pushed it last friday and since then haven't changed anything.

I already pulled and then also fetched the remote repository but the message stays the same. Can someone please help me explain what this means and how I can fix it? I don't want to push some commit to the repository that I don't remember!

And also; what does the "(origin/main, origin/HEAD)" next to my commit id mean?

Comment: Is it possible you pulled in that commit from another branch? Or, maybe someone pushed that commit to `main`, you pulled it after that, and then that person (or someone else) decided that commit shouldn't be on `main`, so they removed it and force pushed `main` without that commit? If they did that, they should have told everyone that this happened so anyone (like you) who already pulled it could take steps to remove it.

Comment: Can you show the output of `git status` and `git log` as well as the history of the corresponding branch on GitLab (ofc redact any private information but make sure we can still see which commit relates to which)?